# How to reference variables from a list when looping over variables using "for"

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am a beginner at R coming from Stata and my first head ache is to figure out how I can loop over a list of names conducting the same operation to all names. The names are variables coming from a data frame. I tried defining a list in this way: `mylist<- c("df$name1", "df$name2")` and then I tried: `for (i in mylist) { i }`  which I hoped would be equivalent to writing `df$name1` and then `df$name2`  to make R print the content of the variables with the names `name1` and `name2` from the data frame `df`. I tried other commands like deleting a variable `i=NULL` within the `for` command, but that didn't work either. I would greatly appreciate if someone could tell me what am I doing wrong? I wonder if it has somethign to do with the way I write the i, maybe R does not interpret it to mean the elements of my character vector.

For more clarification I will write out the code I would use for Stata in this instance. Instead of asking Stata to print the content of a variable I am asking it to give summary statistics of a variable i.e. the no. of observations, mean, standard deviation and min and max using the summarize command. In Stata I don't need to refer to the dataframe as I ususally have only one dataset in memory and I need only write:

```
foreach i in name1 name2 { #name1 and name2 being the names of the variables
  summarize `i' 
}
```

So far, I don't manage to do the same thing using the `for` function in R, which I naivly thought would be:

```
mylist<-c("df$name1", "df$name2") 
  for (i in mylist) {
    summary(i) 
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried `print(i)`?

Comment: Yes, and this prints the "names" of the elements from the mylist vector I defined, but not the actual content of the variable with that name. I want to do things to the actual variable, but I don't know how to refer to the list items (i.e. the "i"s) when writing my code.

Answer (score 0):

you probably just need to print the name to see it. For example, if we have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame("A" = "a", "B" = "b", "C" = "c")

df
# >   A B C
# > 1 a b c

names(df)
# "A" "B" "C"
```

We can operate on the names using a for loop on the `names(df)` vector (no need to define a special list).

```
for (name in names(df)){
  print(name)
  # your code here
}
```

Comment: I know about the ```names()``` function, but the point with making a list was that I wanted to do operations on a subset of the variables in my data frame. I know how to do that one by one, but I wanted a way to easily repeat the operation. The ```print(name)``` command works in that it then prints the names as characters: ```"name1"``` and ```"name2"```, but not the actual content of those variables, which is what I wanted. I want to do more advanced things than print the content of the variable, but it was a way to learn how to correctly refer to the variables in the list I defined.

Comment: Okay, you probably don't want a for loop at all then. For example, if you want to summarise your variables, you can just call `summary(df)`. More generally, the vector can be accessed using `df$name`, and updated using something like `df$name <- log(df$name)`

Comment: I was just using ```summarize``` as an example to learn the ```for``` loop function. In reality, as I explained above to NickCHK, I am trying to substring a lot of variables and make new ones that contain a subset string of the original ones.  I will use these variables to further generate new variables based on logical expressions evaluated against the subset string variables. Each original variable has a complex number in its name that I want to keep as part of the new variable name. If you know of easier ways to do this, please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

R is a little more reticent to let you use strings/locals as code than Stata is. You can do it with functions like `eval` but in general that's not the ideal way to do it.

In the case of variable names, though, you're in luck, as you can use a string to pull out a variable from a `data.frame` with `[[]]`. For example:

```r
df <- data.frame(a = 1:10,
                 b = 11:20,
                 c = 21:30)

for (i in c('a','b')) {
  print(i)
  print(summary(df[[i]]))
}
```

Notes:

1. if you want an object printed from inside a `for` loop you need to use `print()`.
2. I'm assuming that you're using the `summary()` function just as an example and so need the loop. But if you really just want a summary of each variable, `summary(df)` will do them all, or  `summary(df[,c('a','b')])` to just do `a` and `b`. Or check out the `stargazer()` function in the `stargazer` package, which has defaults that will feel pretty comfortable for a Stata user.

Comment: That was really helpful! The next thing I wanted to do was to store the results of the summary command into two different vectors with different names, like sum_a and sum_b. Writing ```sum_i<-summary(df[[i]])``` within the loop didn't work. I am trying to learn this loop function so that I can substring a lot of variables to make new ones. The names of the variables are complex numbers that I want to keep as part of the new variable names just with slight modifications. There may be easier ways of doing this in R that I don't know. If there are and you know of them, please let know.

Comment: Getting that to work using the object names will be a pain. You're probably better off storing those vectors inside a list.
my_sums <- list()
Then in the loop:
my_sums[[i]] <- summary(df[[i]])